# How to deal with NULL values in MySQL from Python

Tags: python, mysql

I need some help in order to deal with NULL values in MySQL using Python. This is my code:

```
import MySQLdb

# This function connects to the MySQL database
def db_connect():
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host=HOST, user=USER, passwd=PASSWD, db=DATABASE, charset="utf8")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit("Can't connect to database")
    return db

def store(project_title, description, website, start_date):
    try:
        cursor = db.cursor()

        insert_projects_query = "INSERT INTO projects (title, description, website, start_date) VALUES ('"+project_title+"','"+description+"','"+website+"','"+start_date+"') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title`='"+project_title+"'"   

        cursor.execute(insert_projects_query)
        db.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

I don't know how to store `NULL` if a field, e.g. `start_date` has the value "NA". Can I somehow directly assign null to `start_date` or should I just exclude it from INSERT query? My table in the database is created in such a way that by default these fields are NULL values.

Comment: Exclude it from the INSERT query.

Comment: @AakashVerma: it means that I should use a lot of if-then rules to check each field in my real code...

Comment: @AakashVerma: The correct solution is to assign None values to fields and that's it.